# Find formula for purchasing progressively less quantity at decreasing prices but maintain 60% average purchase price?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sorry, folks, my terminology is rusty, so I lack the correct mathematical terms to describe my question. This will be in plain English.

The question is find a formula that describes the progression of quantities to purchase at regular decreasing price intervals while maintaining 60% average purchase price.

This relates to theoretical plan is to purchase an asset at price X and take profit if the prices goes up. However, if it goes down then progressively purchase at decreasing sizes to retain a 60% average purchase price between highest and lowest price.

Using the formula, it can be solved for A) the quantity to purchase at a new price. Or B) given a quantity, at what exact price to purchase to maintain 60% average?

Here's an example and clarification of the 60% average:

```
1000 at $10.00   ==>   1st purchase
    
     666 at $ 9.00   ==>   2nd purchase

Average purchase price is now $9.60 or 60% between highest and lowest price. 
    
     555 at $ 8.00   ==>   3rd purchase. Average $9.20 or 60%.
    
     493 at $ 7.00   ==>   4th purchase. Average $8.80 or 60%
```

So what is formula to describe the progression:

1000, 666, 555, 493, and so on.

By the way, those aren't perfectly 60% above, there all a small fraction over 60%.